# create facebook canvas app

Tags: javascript, facebook, ssl, canvas

i have been trying to create Facebook canvas app, but all i get is null page inside canvas. the page inside canvas does not get shown.

could it be because i do not have SSL certificate?  here is the entire code of webpage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1677594719153188',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.5'
    });

    // ADD ADDITIONAL FACEBOOK CODE HERE
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
  <h1 id="fb-welcome">hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

What am i doing wrong? why does not `hello` appear inside canvas and why do i get  chromes broken page image instead?

If not having an SSL certificate is the reason, how can i bypass it?

The webpage i want to create canvas app from is http://nikolozasatiani.com

Thanks

Comment: you are using https but not have ssl certificate? i mean you are using IIS Temporary certificate?

Comment: what is exact address you put in app domain or canvas URL? it will not accept http only https.

Comment: http://nikolozasatiani.com  i dont have https,  i only have http. :( how can i  get https easily? are there any ways to practice creating fb apps without https?    thanks a lot.

Comment: you can use localhost while practicing. or you can get temporary SSL certificate from https://www.startssl.com/ .

Comment: Better Idea would be using localhost where you can debug also.

Comment: thanks a lot. and one more question please . i want to make restaurant menu app.  can i  use wordpress  theme as an "app" which gets shown through canvas?

Comment: you can use any thing on website. app is just a interface to show your content on web page. like iframe.

Comment: thanks a lot.  it is a pity, there are no ways to up vote your comments. thanks again

Comment: not a problem, i am just here to help out not to make my reputation high only.

Comment: https://apps.facebook.com/1677546125824714/   check it out, thanks to you.